# MySQL where on indexed column and not indexed behavior

Tags: mysql, sql

does MySQL where flow works from left to right ?

i want to do a where on an indexed column and only on the results anther filter based on columns. the problem is i don`t know if query will run on the whole table or not

the table columns are  `user_id(indexed) , min_margin , equity`

now in my query i want to do `where user_id=1 and  (min_margin > equity  )`

Comment: No, the dbms server chooses the optimal order.

Comment: The answer is the usual: write the query in a form that makes it readable, trust the server to rearrange it for the optimal execution plan, and only start worrying about rearranging your query if you can prove that the resulting plan is suboptimal and that your rearrangements can help that.

Comment: What data type is user Id out of curiosity